# Looking for how to write verbose or debug string messages to PowerShell runspace without C# Cmdlet definition

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a C# class library that provides a number of interfaces that can be called from PowerShell scripts (.PS1) and Advanced Modules (.PSM1).  I have a static method to write verbose and debug messages to the console using the `System.Console` class:

```c#
public class Write
{

        public static void Verbose(string msg, string source)
        {

            if (Config.EnableVerbose)
            {

                ConsoleColor originalForeGroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
                ConsoleColor originalBackGroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.Write("VERBOSE: {0} {1}{2}", source, msg, Environment.NewLine);
                Console.ForegroundColor = originalForeGroundColor;
                Console.BackgroundColor = originalBackGroundColor;

            }

       }

}
```

However, when those messages are displayed in a PowerShell console, they cannot be captured using redirection, like with `Out-File`, `>&0` or even with `Start-Transcript`.

I have read `about_Redirection`, and using the redirect modifiers does not capture the console output. For instance, using a PowerShell Advanced Function (aka Cmdlet) I have written:

`Get-CommandTrace -ScriptBlock { Get-Resource } *> C:\Temp\capture.log`

The `Get-CommandTrace` Cmdlet sets the `$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'` during the ScriptBlock execution, and does capture the verbose from `Get-Resource` output there.  But does not capture the Console output from my C# library.

So, my question is simply:  Can a C# class that is not a Cmdlet class, nor inherited class, be able to write output to the existing PowerShell runspace it is being called from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:

- **This is *not* a complete answer**, because it has severe limitations - though it may work for specific use cases.
- The original form of this answer used [since-deprecated PowerShell SDK method `.CreateNestedPipeline()`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellStandard/issues/42#issuecomment-516255508), which cannot be used anymore if you're writing your code against the [PowerShellStandard library](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellStandard) for cross-platform and cross-edition compatibility (code that should run in both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell Core, on all supported platforms).
  Chris (the OP) himself found a compatible alternative, which the current form of this answer is based on.

---

The challenge is to write to the *invoking pipeline's* output streams (as you've observed writing via `Console` is unrelated to PowerShell's output streams and prints directly to the console, with no ability to capture or redirect such output in PowerShell).

While you can obtain a reference to the invoking *runspace*, there is no way I know of to obtain a reference to the *running pipeline*.

Using the invoking runspace you can write to PowerShell's output streams via a *new* pipeline, but that comes with **severe limitations**:

- You **cannot directly write to the caller's *success output stream*** (`1`) that way; that is, while you can call cmdlets that target the *other* streams, such as `Write-Verbose`, **`Write-Output` / implicit output does *not* work**.
- Capturing the output from this nested pipeline in a variable or sending it through the pipeline requires enclosing the method call in `(...)` (or `$(...)` or `@(...)`) in addition to applying the appropriate redirection to the success output stream (e.g., `4>&1` for the verbose stream).

See the code comments for details.

```bash
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
  using System.Management.Automation;

  public class Write
  {

      public static void Verbose(string msg)
      {
        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace)) {
          // IMPORTANT: Use .AddScript(), not .AddCommand().
          //            Even though .AddCommand() + .AddParameter() is arguably a cleaner way to
          //            formulate the command, it results in output that cannot be captured.
          //            As noted, Write-Output / success-stream output does NOT work.
          ps.AddScript("Write-Verbose '" + msg.Replace("'", "''") + "'").Invoke();
        }
      }

  }
'@

#"

$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
    
# Regular output to the verbose stream.
Write-Verbose 'msg1'

# Verbose output via the custom type.
[Write]::Verbose('msg2')

# SUPPRESSING and REDIRECTING TO A FILE work.
[Write]::Verbose('msg3') 4> $null
[Write]::Verbose('msg4') 4> t.txt

# By default, REDIRECTING TO THE STANDARD OUTPUT STREAM (1) 
# works only for the OUTSIDE, i.e. for CALLERS of this script.
[Write]::Verbose('msg5') 4>&1

# Redirecting to the standard output stream (1) can also be used to:
#  * CAPTURE the result INSIDE your script
#  * SEND THE RESULT THROUGH THE PIPELINE, 
# additionally invoke the method call enclosed in (...) or $(...) or @(...)
$out = ([Write]::Verbose('msg6') 4>&1); "captured: [$out]"
([Write]::Verbose('msg7') 4>&1) | ForEach-Object { "piped: [$_]" }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I stumbled across some code that actually showed me nested pipelines, as the `Runspace` class didn't have a method to attach to an existing one.  Only to create a new or new nested pipeline.  Attempting to use CreateNewPipeline method resulted in an error, which was expected.  I'll have to experiment with your guidance.

Comment: Even though you stated your answer is incomplete, it does work for my needs.  I do wish there was a way or method to attach to an existing PowerShell session/pipeline.  But I marked your response as an acceptable answer.  Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer above from mklement0 is a good one, it will not work if you attempt to use it with PowerShellCore or targeting .NetStandard 2.0 as the `CreateNestedPipeline` API is deprecated.  (See [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellStandard/issues/42#issuecomment-516255508) thread on the PowerShellStandard GitHub repo.)

So, instead, I have this working code:

```bsh
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

    public class Write
    {

        public static void Verbose(string msg)
        {

            using (PowerShell initialPowerShell = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace))
            {

                initialPowerShell.Commands.AddScript("Write-Verbose " + msg.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\" -v");
                initialPowerShell.Invoke();

            }

        }

    }
'@

$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

# Regular output to the verbose stream.
Write-Verbose 'msg1'

# Verbose output via the custom type.
# !! This can NOT be redirected from the outside.
[Write]::Verbose('msg2')

# !! SUPPRESSING or REDIRECTING TO A FILE only works
# !! when DIRECTLY APPLIED to the method call.
[Write]::Verbose('msg3') 4> $null
[Write]::Verbose('msg4') 4> t.txt

# !! REDIRECTING TO THE STANDARD OUTPUT STREAM (1) for the OUTSIDE works,
# !! but obviously it then merges with success output.
[Write]::Verbose('msg5') 4>&1

# !! To REDIRECT TO THE STANDARD OUTPUT STREAM (1) and capture the result
# !! INSIDE your script, invoke the method call in  (...) or $(...) or @(...)
$out = ([Write]::Verbose('msg6') 4>&1)
"[$out]"
```

Which works with PowerShell 5.1 for Windows, PowerShell Core 6.2.2 for Windows and Linux (Ubuntu/Debian).

I will still leave mklement0 reply marked as the answer to the original question.  I'm just adding another one based on research I had compiled over the past few days on migrating my class library to .NetStandard 2.0.