# How to pass flag variables between Powershell and c#?

Tags: c#, powershell, environment-variables, global-variables

I have a script that starts a powershell job with a script block that contains c# code in it.

Right now I have a sleep command in place to allow the code to posture itself properly, but a cleaner way (if possible) would be to have the psjob c# code set a flag and allow the rest of my code to start as soon as it can rather than wait the 5 second sleep as a catch all. Is this possible?

```
$containerScript = {a mix of c# and powershell}
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $containerScript ;
sleep 5; # wait here for c# code to set up
Connect-MsolService;
```

So if I set a variable in the c# psjob script, say `bool started = true;`how could I read that with a loop instead of using `sleep 5` in the powershell code shown above, that's outside of the psjob runspace and the c# code?

Comment: I figured this much out @mklement0

$result = Receive-Job -id $returnValue.Id -InformationVariable infovariable;

I can see anything I use with "Write-Host" inside of the psjobs script from that output, but I don't see the c# Console.Write("adfadf") type outputs?

Comment: Yes I have it as a loop. I need to know how to pass values from the c# code to the psjobs wrapper and I can make it work?

Comment: I can't return a value as it would stop the c# code execution, which is why I wanted to do a flag readable by both code sets. Is there a way to write to the pipeline without using a return function? Something like Pipeline.Write("asdfaf") ?

Comment: Possibly something like this in the c# portion?

                    `Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                    `rs.Open();
                    `Pipeline pipe = rs.CreatePipeline();
                    `pipe.Commands.AddScript("Write-Host loopFirstTime");
                    `pipe.Invoke();
                    `rs.Close();

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is for a custom .NET type's method to *asynchronously* write to PowerShell's output streams to signal a condition to the calling PowerShell code even before the method itself returns.

`Console.WriteLine()` can *not* do that, because it writes directly to the console, bypassing PowerShell's output streams altogether.

The best approach would be to implement your .NET type as a PowerShell *cmdlet*, which would allow you to use its `.Write*()` methods to write instantly to PowerShell's output streams.

If that is not an option, you can use the PowerShell SDK to write to the calling runspace's output streams, which has its limitations, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54915511/45375).

Here is a demonstration of the technique adapted to your use case:

```
# Start a background job.
$jb = Start-Job { 

  # Compile a sample type from C# source code.
  Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
  using System.Management.Automation;

  public class SomeClass
  {

      public static string DoStuff()
      {
        // ... perform initialization

        // Instantly signal to the calling PowerShell session that initialization has
        // completed, by calling Write-Information, which writes to the information stream (6).
        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace)) {
          // IMPORTANT: Use .AddScript(), not .AddCommand().
          //            Even though .AddCommand() + .AddParameter() is arguably a cleaner way to
          //            formulate the command, it results in output that cannot be captured.
          // Even though Write-Information is silent by default, the information *is* written to the stream.
          ps.AddScript("Write-Information 'Initialized'").Invoke();
        }

        // Do other things.
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        return "Done";

      }

  }
'@

  # Call the sample type's method, which runs for a while, and partway
  # through signals completion of the initialization portion with Write-Host output.
  [SomeClass]::DoStuff()

 }

 # Wait for output from the job and output it as it arrives. 
 while ($jb.HasMoreData) {

  # Receive pending stream output from the background job, capturing information-stream output separately.
  Receive-Job $jb -InformationVariable iv

  # Check if the initialization notification was received via the information stream.
  # Note that $iv is always a *collection* type, even if there's only 1 message,
  # and that the elements of that collection are of type [System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord]
  if ($iv -and $iv[0].ToString() -eq 'Initialized') { 'Now initialized.'}

  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100

}

Remove-Job $jb # clean up.
```